# Change default naming conventions in PhpStorm 2016.3

Tags: php, phpstorm

I work on a project with some specific naming conventions which are different from the default ones in PhpStorm 2016.3. For example, when I need to create a method and start typing its parameters, autocomplete tries to help me in the following way:

```
function meh(MehObject $mehObject, AutoComplete $autoComplete) {}
```

I need something different to appear by default as I type, though:

```
function meh(MehObject $meh_object, AutoComplete $auto_complete) {}
```

If I succeed changing the convention in PhpStorm, I'll only need to press enter once after `$`, and a valid name will appear. As for now, I need to type the full name with an underscore (or even a few underscores). That is unproductive.

How do I change the default naming conventions for the given example and other cases in PhpStorm 2016.3?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207014345-Autocomplete-change-suggested-option-from-camelCase-to-Underscores- although there might be plugins for that.

Comment: Try **latest 2016.3.1 EAP build** (or .. maybe even wait for final release where more options should be available) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26738#comment=27-1756981

Comment: @LazyOne It would be great if you post this link, probably even with the screenshot, with a little explanation as an answer, so that I could accept it.

Comment: Have you tried and it's working for you? Maybe this specific part is not yet implemented or not available in currently available build (which is 1 week old .. and they have implemented few more related tickets since then)

Comment: I'll wait for a more stable release, or maybe will try it at home later, but I guess it still answers my question - the feature is freshly implemented and looks like it does exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PhpStorm 2016.3.1** has such options -- [WI-26738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26738).

Here is a screenshot of the Settings/Preferences (image taken from [official comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26738#comment=27-1756981)) -- notice the bottom part of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Please note that there's no more "Capitalize first letter" option.